# html object tag border issue

Tags: html, css

I have added an html object tag in my page, it displays the content ok in ff but in IE it also shows up a border. 
How do I remove it.

Comment: You should post your code too.

Comment: here is the code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uF2Xh/ 
I do not want that border around object element. If you place the code in a html page and view in FF its ok but if you view in IE that border shows up. I do not want that...

Comment: I am using IE 7 and FF 3.6.10

Answer (score 0):

I think you're describing a need for the following:

```
<object style="border:0px;">
```

It would be better to put this in a CSS file.  To have no borders around any `<object>` element, put the following line in a CSS file:

```
object { border:0px; }
```

Comment: @Rahul Utb: Ok.  Could you paste the HTML code you're using (in the question), then?

Comment: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/uF2Xh/
Just you can re assemble in a normal html page and see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deprecated attribute `border` which you could also use, although without your code it's hard to say whether it would work.

`<object border="0">`